# How to Prove Theorem le_zero in Lean4: If x ≤ 0, then x = 0?

Tags: lean4, natural-numbers

I am playing the Natural Number Game found [here](https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/hhu-adam/NNG4/world/LessOrEqual/level/5) and am trying to prove a theorem in Lean4. The theorem states that if a natural number `x` is less than or equal to 0, then `x` must be 0. The formal statement is `∀ (x : ℕ), x ≤ 0 → x = 0`.

Here's my current code:

```
theorem le_zero (x : ℕ) (hx : x ≤ 0) : x = 0 := by {
  apply le_trans x 0 x at hx,
  cases x with d,
  rfl,
  symm,
  -- Now I have a goal of `succ d = 0`
  apply zero_le at hx,
  -- Stuck here, it says 'oops'
}
```

I applied `le_trans` and then used `cases` to handle the base case `x = 0` and the successor case `x = succ d`. The base case is easily solved with `rfl`, but I'm stuck on the successor case.

Comment: Hint 1: Note that in the natural numbers, `succ d` can never be `0`.  So your mistake has to be before you got to the goal `succ d = 0`.  Hint 2: Have you tried it on paper?

Answer (score 3):

this is my proof that uses the rules of the game

```
cases hx
contrapose! h
symm
intro t
apply eq_zero_of_add_right_eq_zero at t
apply h at t
exact t
```

Not sure if `cases` is allowed at the beginning without a `with` but it seems to be accepted, Game will accept this proof.

---

Edit: Someone posted another shorter proof, but I don't see their proof anymore, so here it goes

```
cases hx with a ha
exact eq_zero_of_add_right_eq_zero _ _ ha.symm
```